# Markov chain of normally distributed variables

Tags: probability-distributions, markov-chains

Suppose $(x_1, x_2, \dots)$ is sequence of random variables defined as follows.

$x_1 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, i.e. the distribution of $x_1$ is the standard normal distribution.

$x_{n+1} \sim \mathcal{N}(\frac{x_n}{2}, 1)$.

How do I determine the probability that $\sum_n \frac{x_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges?

It seems like one needs techniques from Markov chain theory and I'm not too familiar with that. Is there any suggestion on how to solve this (or how to start thinking about this) problem?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use the law of iterated expectations to compute $E[X_n]$ and $E[X_n^2]$ recursively (indeed using the Markov property and assuming independence of the past).  You can also get  $E[X_nX_m]$.  So you can compute the variance of your sum.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Sorry for my ignorance but how does knowing the variance of the sum give the probability of convergence of the sum? They must be related but I don't see it at the moment.

Comment: sorry, I'm a little bit late to the thread. The problem is very interesting. I went over the comment but I don't see why $X_i$ and $Y_j$ are independent ( $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are of course independent). Actually, I dont think that is correct, $X_i$ is only independent from $Y_i$ and is always correlated with $Y_j$ for $j>i$.

Answer (score 0):

Computing precise things like mean and variance helps you "get to know" your process.  Knowing whether the tail of your process has variance that, for example,  goes to zero, or a positive number, or infinity, gives insight and helps you know if convergence in the "mean square" sense is possible.  This is why I gave my above comment. In some cases such information can also help determine if "almost sure" convergence holds.

#### Related starter problem:

Suppose $\{Y_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of i.i.d. Gaussian random variables $N(0,1)$.  Can you say what happens to $\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i/\sqrt{i}$ as $n \rightarrow\infty$?

#### Some more structure on your problem:

It may help to view your process as

$$ X_{n+1} = (1/2)X_n + Y_n \quad, \forall n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$$

From this, can you compute means, variances, $E[X_nX_m]$ quantities, and make any other useful observations?

Comment: Thanks again for your guidance. I am working through your suggestions now. Please let me know if what I have are reasonable.For each $n$,

Comment: Thanks again for your guidance; I'm pretty new to this subject. I am working through your suggestions now. Please let me know if what I have are reasonable. For each $n$, I know that $s_n=\sum^n_i Y_i/\sqrt{i} \sim N(0, \sum_i 1/i)$ so the variance of $s_n \rightarrow \infty$, right? This means the sequence s_n diverges, right? However, the random variable $X_{n+1} = (1/2)X_n + Y_n$ is a bit difficult for me. For instance if I know $X_1$ and $Y_1$ are independent, then I know what $X_2$ is and can compute $E[X_2], Var[X_2] etc$ but is it clear that $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are independent?

Comment: I Made a mistake stating the problem. I should have said: the conditional distribution of $x_{n+1}$ GIVEN $x_n$ is $N(x_n,/2 1)$.

Comment: Ok. I think I made some progress. I have that for each $n$, $E[X_n] =0$; for example, $E[X_2] = E[E[X_2|X_1]] = E[X_1/2] = 0$ because $E[X_1]=0$. I think also $Var[X_n] = 1$ for all $n$. Now $E[X_nX_m] = Cov(X_n,X_m) + E[X_n]E[X_m] = Cov(X_n,X_m)$. I am not sure how to compute $Cov(X_n,X_m)$ at the moment.

Comment: Yes, in the case $\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i/\sqrt{i}$, we know this is Gaussian $N(0, \sum_{i=1}^n 1/i)$, and this Gaussian variable gets a variance that goes to infinity.  So it does not converge to a valid random variable. The $X_{n+1} = (1/2)X_n + Y_n$ is more complicated, but I wonder if you can decompose into its components. I agree $E[X_n]=0$ for all $n$, but the variance is not 1 for all $n$, I would consider $Var(X_{n+1})=E[X_{n+1}^2] = E[(\frac{1}{2}X_n+Y_n)^2]$.  The variance will be $\geq 1$ for all $n$ (assuming $X_n, Y_n$ are independent).

Comment: Oh right. You are right that $Var(X_n) \geq 1$ for all $n$ if $X_n, Y_n$ are independent. I do not see how to compute $Var(X_n)$ without this assumption. Proceeding with the assumption, we need to show $E[(\sum_{i=m}^n \frac{X_n}{\sqrt{n}})^2]$ goes to $\infty$ as $n,m\rightarrow \infty$ (I think we can then conclude the probability of the sum in the original question converges is 0, right?). I think knowing $Var(X_n)>=1$ is good enough for this and one needs to compute various $E[X_iX_j]$ as you mentioned above. I do think that $E[X_iX_j] >=0$ if we assume the $Y_i, X_j$'s are independent.

Comment: I would fix a tail index $m$ and then show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} E[(\sum_{i=m}^n X_i/\sqrt{i})^2] = \infty$ (this would show the tail variance does not vanish, regardless of where you start the tail index $m$, so mean-square convergence is impossible). I agree $E[X_iX_j]\geq 0$ so you can ignore those terms to get a bound that includes only expectations of the $X_i^2$ quantities.  To argue about sample path convergence or probability 1 results, you may need to use distribution information, which may arise by decomposing $X_n$.

Comment: Thanks. I can show lim$n\rightarrow \infty E[(\sum^n_{i=m} X_i / \sqrt{i})^2] = \infty$ with the assumptions above.

Comment: Can you get the distribution of $X_n$?

Comment: I am still not sure how to get a closed-form formula for the distribution of $X_n$. I am thinking of using the formula $f_{X_2}(X_2|X_1) = f(X_1,X_2)/f_{X_1}(X_1)$ to compute the joint distribution $f(X_1, X_2)$ and go from there.

Comment: But you know $X_2 = (1/2)X_1 + Y_1$.

Comment: You are right! Sums of two normal distributions are normal.